# How to display static control elements on LayeredWindow

Tags: c++, winapi

I create window 
`hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, szWindowClass, szTitle,0,
       CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);`

Then I display png image

```
CImage img;
img.Load(Path);
int iWidth = img.GetWidth();
int iHeight = img.GetHeight();
HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
HDC hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, iWidth, iHeight);
HBITMAP hBmpOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hDC, hBmp);
img.Draw(hDC,0, 0, iWidth, iHeight, 0, 0, iWidth, iHeight);
BLENDFUNCTION blend = {0};
blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
blend.BlendFlags=0;
blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
POINT ptPos = {0, 0};
SIZE sizeWnd = {iWidth, iHeight};
POINT ptSrc = {0, 0};
UpdateLayeredWindow(hWnd, hdcScreen, &ptPos, &sizeWnd, hDC, &ptSrc, 0, &blend, ULW_ALPHA);
SelectObject(hDC, hBmpOld);
DeleteObject(hBmp);
DeleteDC(hDC);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
```

And I want on this window create some static control elements, for example progress bar.

```
#define ID_MainProgressBar 2000
HWND MainProgressBar=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED,PROGRESS_CLASS,NULL,WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|PBS_SMOOTH,200,200,180,100,hwnd1,(HMENU)ID_MainProgressBar,hInst,NULL);
```

And I can't see this element. Another question, where need call HWND MainProgressBar=CreateWindowEx in callback main window or when I create main window?

Comment: Per-pixel alpha is very troublesome with any code that uses GDI to paint, like progressbar.  GDI doesn't know beans about alpha and renders 24bpp.  You can't see it.

Comment: GDI+ is better in rendering with Alpha-channel. And it is an official part of Windows, not just another Library from somewhere off the internet.

Comment: I used GDI+ and almost all works fine,but when I display png image, background getting of my first window and then when I switched windows(alt+tab) background doesn't change rather my background doesn't redraw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `UpdateLayeredWindow()`, you are responsible for drawing the contents of the entire window into a bitmap, and then give that bitmap to `UpdateLayeredWindow()` each time the window contents change.  Needless to say, that does not work when there are child controls involved.  Instead, use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` to activate alpha/transparency on an otherwise-normal window (so you can use child controls normally) and draw your PNG onto the window in response to the standard `WM_PAINT` message.

Comment: Where call SetLayeredWindowAttributes() instead UpdateLayeredWindow()?

Comment: Call `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` after you create the window, or whenever you need to update the window's alpha/transparency value.

Comment: One more question, for display png image use CImage or GDI+?

Comment: Use whatever you want, since you would be drawing onto the `HDC` of the window in your `WM_PAINT` message handler.

Comment: hmm try use CImage but I can't see my picture

Comment: at last) use GDI+ and all works fine. Some interesting fact, when I display png it so colored seems like many times this image was redrawing, but load another png it displaying perfect.However I thank you for help!